# Query Information_schema for multiple tables, include table in query result

Tags: mysql

I am querying a mysql, wordpress database looking for sites using a specific plugin for web reidrects.  I don't know what tables the links live in and the tables are formatted in the following format: wp_%%_postmeta, the %% value is not always sequential and not each table contains the value's I'm querying for.

I developed a query to search for

This query works to return the values I want but I cannot tie the results of this data to each row's respective table.  I can't figure out how to get the

```
SET GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN  = 50000;
SELECT 
CONCAT('select * from (select post_id, meta_value from ',
        GROUP_CONCAT(tb
            SEPARATOR ' where meta_key like "_gdd_speedy_page_redirect" union select post_id, meta_value from '),
        ' where meta_key like "_gdd_speedy_page_redirect") as Wdp_tables ')
INTO @wdp_table_query FROM
(SELECT 
    CONCAT(table_schema, '.', table_name) tb
FROM
    information_schema.tables
WHERE
    table_name LIKE '%_postmeta') A;
SELECT @wdp_table_query;
prepare stmt from @wdp_table_query;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

The data that is returned looks as follows:

```
POST_ID  |  META_VALUE
29       |  URL_HERE
493      |  NEXT_URL_HERE
```

I need the data to return like so:

```
TABLE           |  POST_ID  |  META_VALUE
wp_03_postmeta  |  2        |  URL_HERE
wp_74_postmeta  |  493      |  NEXT_URL_HERE
```

Is there any way I can insert the corresponding table being queried in the select statment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move `select post_id, meta_value from` completely into the group_concat, you should be able to just insert the table name into the select list; something like this:

`GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('select "', A.tb, '" AS theTable, post_id, meta_value from'...`

I haven't looked too closely at your exact, desired query, but in these cases SEPARATOR can often be simply `' UNION '`.

---

General format

```
CONCAT([wrapper_start]
   , GROUP_CONCAT([table_query... built from a CONCAT] SEPARATOR ' UNION ')
   , [wrapper_end]) AS query
```

*Making `information_schema.tables` a subquery seems like over complicating things though.*

Comment: Thanks!  I hadn't thought to put quotes around tb to populate the table, putting it on one line made things easier as well.